# Creating an Installer package

Tags: installation

So I have a compliled matlab code, 'Example.exe'...I want to create an installer package that does the following:

My exe file will reside on a network drive.

My installer will first ask the user for the installation path.

It will then copy the exe (along with some other supporting files) in the given path....IF the folder already exists, it will ask the user for overwrite confirmation.

After the copying is done, my installer will ask the user if they want to install the MCR and accordingly install it(or not).

After everything is done, a shortcut to the exe is created on the desktop.

My question is, is there some installer package generator that can do all this ?? I understand matlab can create an installer package, but I want my file to be copied from the network drive. I also don't have Visual Studio so, can't create an msi.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple way to do this, you'll need a software called IExpress, It can create a self-extracting executable (.EXE) or a compressed Cabinet (.CAB) file using the provided interface (IExpress Wizard). Its included in all versions of windows (I think..). To run the IExpress Wizard, go to your local drive then: Windows\System32, Search for "iexpress" then run the program.
then...

Follow these steps:

1. Run iexpress.exe 
2. Create a new 'Self Extraction Directive' file 
3. Extract files only 
4. Specify the title, promt user options, license, etc
5. Start adding files to your package
7. Specify other options (window, message)
8. Enter the path where you want your package to be.

Then you're almost done, create your package (might take a few mins), distribute it, upload it and all.

For more details visit http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-an-exe-installation-file/

Comment: [**It is not advisable to use IExpress due to some major security flaws**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress#Security). [About bootstrappers and installation bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48363090/129130).

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do that. But if you tightly tied to Windows platform, you definitely can learn Windows Installer technology. It's NOT related to Visual Studio!

Just download [WiX toolset](http://wix.codeplex.com/downloads/get/482065) (it is free and Open Source!) and learn MSDN docs about Windows Installer.

But it is complex way, remember. You can spent months learning how to make great Windows installers.

Ofcourse, you can use Inno Setup or NSIS, but I don't recommend that, because them re-engineer installer technology instead of native Windows Installer's.

If you want, I can learn you by Skype or something like. :-)
Or (isn't great offer?) I can write the installer for you and send you all code and describe which for what is.

Answer (score -1):

Use iExpress! Available from win xoxo and over (xp)

With windows 8 pro you can make a package with your voice! Only with win 8 or 8.1 pro.

Comment: Please read [answer]. You've just given us a term to search. And note that iExpress was already recommended in [this 8 year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16261883/354577).