# Application Installer: Microsoft database engine 2010 not available under pre-requisites

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer

I have a windows form c-sharp application developed for windows 10. When I am trying to make installer, I cannot find "microsoft database engine 2010" (important for my app)  under the "prerequisite" as shown below:

[image]

I do not want my customer to separately download it and install it. So is there a way I can generate an installer that will install complete software along with microsoft database engine 2010 ( if it is not already installed on the system) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this runtime, but did you do a Google search? It looks like the runtime is available: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255. I am sure you did. Perhaps it is the wrong one? Or a format you can't use I guess.

The downloads are x86 and 64-bit versions in EXE format. The EXE files have embedded MSI files (Windows Installer) that you can extract, or you should be able to just run the EXE in silent mode (probably safest). Do a `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /?` to get a list of parameters.

### Merge Modules

Normally you can use a [merge module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369820(v=vs.85).aspx) to add a runtime component to your own MSI at compile time, but this runtime may not be available in this format. Instead you can use a bootstrapper of some kind to run your own MSI installer and this prerequisite database engine runtime MSI / EXE in sequence (or even just a batch file - see towards the bottom).

### Bootstrappers

[**The WiX toolkit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (which is a better way to make MSI files than Visual Studio Installer Projects - see the link for some details) features a bootstrapper called **Burn** - it can install both EXE and MSI files in sequence. There are also other bootstrappers available, but I haven't tried them. Here is a description of some bootstrappers from earlier: [Wix - How to run/install application without UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148875/wix-how-to-run-install-application-without-ui/48157650#48157650).

As you will see in the link immediately above, there is a sample of the WiX bootstrapper **Burn** in use here: https://github.com/frederiksen/Classic-WiX-Burn-Theme (it even shows a WiX MSI package as well). WiX and Burn does have a learning curve.

There may be simpler options available using `Visual Studio Installer Projects` that I am not aware of, but I think you need a bootstrapper to install several MSI files in sequence. As far as I can see these Installer Projects support only the listed prerequisites that you show in your screenshot to download and install on demand, and they seem to allow the addition of (any) standard merge module. It is very strange that you can't tell the Installer Project's setup.exe to kick off the install of any MSI as a prerequisite considering that the whole feature is made to install prerequisites in the first place. **PhilDW will surely be able to tell you with certainty**.

Commercial tools such as **Advanced Installer** or **Installshield** also have features to allow you to bundle setups, in various formats, together for installation in sequence. It might be a feature in the Premium or most expensive edition in Installshield's case. Not sure for Advanced Installer. **Bogdan Mitrache will be able to tell us** - they may do it better. I don't want to claim something I am not sure of - things like these change as new versions are released (may obviously also be the case for Installshield).

### Batch File, PowerShell Script

In closing I should add that you can obviously use a **batch file** to install files in sequence (or a **PowerShell script** - which would depend on .NET though). For example wrapped in a **[self-extracting archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive)**. You can quickly try the built in `iexpress.exe` self-extracting tool in Windows: Hold down <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> and tap <kbd>R</kbd>, enter `iexpress` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click through the options. [**Be very aware of the security vulnerabilities iexpress suffers from**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress#Security)!

Not sure how well well these wrappers clean up their temporary files (particularly if there are errors during installation) - which could be ugly and annoying, but it should work. A bootstrapper can do a lot more though - such as provide a real GUI for your users and handle error conditions among other things.

Security problems with deployment solutions is a pet peeve of mine, so I want to add a link to this: [Prevent DLL Hijacking Burn with Clean Room](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/5184-burn-clean-room/). A WiX Burn issue fixed in [the latest version of WiX](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/tag/wix3111rtm) (as of Jan.2018). As you can see, the allure and simplicity of `iexpress.exe` generally does not make up for its security shortcomings. It is most definitely not good enough for a world-wide, large-scale, public release.

Should you want to use a batch file or PowerShell for the installation, then the following answer provides some information on using the **msiexec.exe command line**, and there is also a link to another answer which deals with **PowerShell** installation: [How can I use powershell to run through an installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221983/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-run-through-an-installer/46224987#46224987)