# Visual studio installer error with Visual C++ 2017 Runtime Libraries (x64) prerequisite

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, vcredist

I've created the installer for my project without a problem, In project's properties, I included Visual C++ 2017 Runtime Libraries (x64) 2010 and 2017.

But during the installation in the client host, I've got a 'The following package files could not be found:' without specifying much more information.

Is when I checked the temp directory that I've discovered that 'vc2017redist_x64' haven't copied.

With the 2010 version, it seems to work rightly.
Anyone have experienced the same problem?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.9.17.

Comment: What setting have you selected for *"Specify the install location for prerequisites"*? [See this screen shot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48359959/129130) (click image to enlarge). Look at bottom options.

Comment: In my case I selected "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application", but It doesn't really matters. I also tried with the first option (download from internet) and I've got the same error.

Comment: How did you include the "prerequisites"? Any more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with the solution.

The path of the VC++2017 installer in the default  bootstraper package was wrong and installation failed.
So I had to edit the manifest file in 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\ and set the right path.

Once modified, it worked!

Please notice that you can also find the bootstrapper folder location from the Path value in the following registry key:

*HKLM\Software\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper*

On 64-bit systems, use the following registry key:

*HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper*